# VB.net DLL Import from resources

Tags: vb.net, dll, resources, dllimport

I have done quite a bit of research on this and have gotten many solutions that either do not work or i am not implementing correctly.

I have a DLL named MyDLL.dll created as a win32 dll coded in c++.

In VB.net i can call the starting function from the dll by doing this:

```
 <DllImport("MyDll.dll")> Public Shared Function DLL_Function() As Boolean
 End Function
```

What i need is something like this:

```
 <DllImport(My.Resources.MyDLL)> Public Shared Function INJECTION_MAIN() As Boolean
 End Function
```

Newby steps would be nice.

Comment: check the lower right side of the screen under `Related`.  There is a whole list of ...well, related questions Google may not have found.

Comment: This is not possible, a rock-hard Windows operating system requirement for unmanaged executables is that they must be stored in a file on disk.  There is already a very common way to stuff executable files into a single file, everybody calls it setup.exe

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as always; Stackoverflow does not seem to have what i am looking for, at this time.

Comment: No no it is possible, i've done it before.

Comment: No, it is not possible.  If you've done it before then you did it with a .NET assembly.  It contains data, not code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first snippet of code is correct. That is just the wrapper for the function though...

Here is what you want to do:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    'To call your function
    PInvoke.DLL_Function()
End Sub

End Module

'your function wrappers go here
Public Class PInvoke
     <DllImport("MyDll.dll")> Public Shared Function DLL_Function() As Boolean
     End Function
End Class
```